Open Sans Font installation failed
Upon starting QGIS (without loading in any data and/or projects), it produces an error stating "Open Sans font installation failed". Upon opening an existing project the error pops up multiple times as well.
I would imagine this relates to an error with that specific font, but since the error already pops up when starting up QGIS without any data, I wonder where this font is being used. This error is persistent through different versions of QGIS (3.32 & 3.36).
Does anyone happen to know how this error can be resolved?
EDIT: Please find the answer below in the comments.
I have tried changing the "default" font in the settings (Settings - Options - General - Font - ...), but that hasn't solved the issue.

Try downloading Open Sans font and copy the file/s into the fonts folder under your qgis profile.

Have you tried starting QGIS in a new profile with no plugins enabled? IN Settings... User Profiles... Create a new profile and then switch to it - QGIS restarts and should be as plain as possible with no plugins enabled. Sometimes startup errors are plugins.

Thank you for your suggestions. Unfortunately starting QGIS in a new profile without any plugins active does still produce the same error message.
Would you be able to clarify how I would go about downloading and installing fonts?

Are you on windows? I have the same problem with my windows install. I will open a ticket on https://trac.osgeo.org/osgeo4w.

it worked for me after i have downloaded the open sans fonts from google and installed it and restarting QGIS. the file is around 5MB and you will have to extract and install it by opening the font or copy and paste it under fonts folder in C/windows.
the link is: https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Open+Sans

To install the font on windows.  https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/how-to-install-or-remove-a-font-in-windows-f12d0657-2fc8-7613-c76f-88d043b334b8

Thank you so much, that solved the issue perfectly.


Open https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Open+Sans
Click "Get font", "Download all (1)"

Extract Open_Sans.zip,
open (double-click) each of the following files with Windows Font Viewer, and "install"



OpenSans-VariableFont_wdth,wght.ttf
OpenSans-Italic-VariableFont_wdth,wght.ttf


Restart QGIS

NOTE: You can solve the similar error "Ubuntu font installation failed" by using those available in  https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Ubuntu

On a linux system (I tried it with Linux Mint 22) you can go this way: in a terminal you write

sudo apt-get update -y 
sudo apt-get install -y fonts-open-sans

After restart QGIS the error stating "Open Sans font installation failed" does not appear any more.

On Gentoo
emerge -uavDnN media-fonts/open-sans
works.
